# Compiler error in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Here is the error I am getting.

> CruiseShip.h:10: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘::’ token
>
> CruiseShip.cpp:8: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘name’ make: ***
>
> [CruiseShip.o] Error 1

**CruiseShip.h**

```
CruiseShip(std::string name,std::string year, int maxPassengers)::Ship(std::string name,std::string year);
```

**CruiseShip.cpp**

```
CruiseShip(string name, string year, int maxPassengers)::Ship(string name, string year){
    maxPassengers=0;
}
```

These are the line's where the error occurs.

Here is the rest of the code:
**CruiseShip.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Ship.h"
#include "CruiseShip.h"
using namespace std;



CruiseShip(string name, string year, int maxPassengers)::Ship(string name, string year){
    maxPassengers=0;
}

void CruiseShip::setPass(int maxPassengers){
    this->maxPassengers=maxPassengers;
}
int CruiseShip::getPass(){
    return maxPassengers;
}

void CruiseShip::print(){
    cout<<"The name of the ship is "<<getName()<<endl;
    cout<<"The capacity of the ship is "<<maxPassengers<<endl;

}
```

**CruiseShip.h**

```
#ifndef CRUISESHIP_H_
#define CRUISESHIP_H_
#include <string>
class CruiseShip: public Ship{
protected:
    int maxPassengers;
    

public:
    CruiseShip(std::string name,std::string year, int maxPassengers)::Ship(std::string name,std::string year);
    void setPass(int);
    int getPass();
    virtual void print();

};
#endif
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be a template? That's not how you use a template.

Comment: I don't quite see what those lines are supposed to do. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: This simply looks like invalid C++. What you're trying to do?

Comment: @WilliamKappler Given his tags, I would guess he is trying to declare and define constructors of a child class. But I would not put money on that.

Comment: I posted the rest of the code, my apologies.

Comment: Remark: You (most likely accidentally) ignore the value of the parameter `maxPassenger` and always set the member with that name to `0`. If that was on purpose, please tell me or molbdnilo so someone can revert my (then invalid) edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line doesn't seem to make any sense.
What do you think it is supposed to do?

```
CruiseShip(std::string name,std::string year, int maxPassengers)::Ship(std::string name,std::string year);
```

It looks like the start of a constructor for `class CruiseShip`, but then has a scoping (`::`) before starting to look like the constructor for `class Ship`.

Here is what I think you mean:

In Header(.h) file:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using std::string;
class CruiseShip :
    public Ship   // Class inherits from base-class Ship
{
    // Constructor takes 3 parameters:
    CruiseShip(const string& name, const string& year, int maxPassengers);
};
```

In Implementation(.cpp) File:

```
// Implementation of the Constructor, which begins by passing
// name and year to the Base-Class constructor.
// Then completes the constructor by handling the maxPassengers parameter.
CruiseShip::CruiseShip(const string& name, const string& year, int maxPassengers): 
    Ship(name, year)  // Call the base-class constructor
{
    this->maxPassengers = maxPassengers; // Also assign member variable.
}
```

---

A few other notes:

- You should generally pass variables by const-reference if you don't have a good reason for passing by value.  This will avoid needless copy-constructors.
- Avoid the whole `#ifdef - #endif` protection by using `#pragma once`, which is supported by most major compilers now.
- Don't do `using namespace std;`.  It brings in the entire namespace, which is really big.  Just import what you need: `using std::string;`  (see [This Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice))

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, `CruiseShip` inherits from `Ship`.

The declaration should say only what the constructor's prototype is,

```
CruiseShip(std::string name, std::string year, int maxPassengers);
```

and the definition does the initialisation:

```
CruiseShip::CruiseShip(string name, string year, int maxPassengers) 
   : Ship(name, year),
     maxPassengers(maxPassengers) 
{

}
```

Note that there's only a single colon and that the base class initialization doesn't mention the types, just like a function call.
Also, the constructor definition needs the scope specification `CruiseShip::`.

Comment: Was typing this. You're too fast

Comment: You have conflicting variables for `maxPassengers` and you throw away the parameter `maxPassengers` without ever using it.

Comment: Dumb question, the declaration is in the header file right? Because if I change that the compiler won't find a matching function since they differ. @molbdnilo

Comment: @abelenky The conflicting names don't matter for correctness, just for style.

Comment: The conflicting names don't matter ***to the computer***.  They will confuse the heck out of many ***humans***.  Code is written for humans to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Your Ship class has to have something like this :

```
Ship(std::string,std::string);
```

in public declarations. Because this is what you are calling when you give parameters in `CruiseShip`

The way you make a correct constructor with inherence is this way :

```
CruiseShip::CruiseShip(string name, string year, int maxPassengers):Ship(name,year){
    maxPassengers=0;
}
```

You are calling the constructor with parameters `Ship(std::string,std::string)` that takes parameters given by `CruiseShip`. And you simply tell the program which variables you are giving

Your CruiseShip class because it's wrong. You don't tell the program to call Ship first

```
#ifndef CRUISESHIP_H_
#define CRUISESHIP_H_
#include <string>
class CruiseShip: public Ship{
protected:
    int maxPassengers;


public:
    CruiseShip(std::string name,std::string year, int maxPassengers);
    void setPass(int);
    int getPass();
    virtual void print();

};
#endif
```